# How to get last value inserted in a database to generate new one

Tags: c#, sql-server

Using Text Area I'm sending Values to database by clicking button, but I want postID to auto generate how I can do it?

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PostQuery = "INSERT INTO [Post] (PostID,PostDet,Votes,UserID) VALUES('<auto Genatare post ID>','" + TxtPost.Text + "','12','Us001')";
    dbClass.ConnectDataBaseToInsert(PostQuery);
    Response.Redirect("~/computing.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Is `PostID` created as an autogenerated column in DB?

Comment: This is a db question. Make your `PostId` field an identity (if using SQL Server, unsure about other dbs) and it will autogenerate the value for you.

Comment: please add a tag that specifies Database you use

Comment: If PostID is auto-generated in your DB anything you try to save to that column will be discarded

Comment: My Post ID look like "PO0001" like that, when i insert one record and before another record insert i want to get last ID and make it like "PO002" when click on button

Comment: Bad idea, see my post. (I'm going to edit this in a minute)

Comment: @DinoBaba: This is a really bad idea.  Databases have an `IDENTITY` option on columns for a reason, and this is exactly that reason.  Don't re-invent the wheel, mostly because your wheel is going to have race conditions and concurrency problems.  If the business-friendly identifier for that entity needs a `"PO"` prepended to it, do that in the fetching/displaying of the data, not in the persisting of it.

Comment: @David It is possible, but it is a bit more work. I describe this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `PostID` a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column and then pass in a newly generated GUID ([`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Also, please use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection. Especially if the inputs come directly from WEB users.

To do so, change your `ConnectDataBaseToInsert` method to not take SQL text, but an `SqlCommand` which you prepare with the respective parameters.

---

From your comment to the question: The PostID should be like `PO0001`. Then the only way to do it properly and to respect for concurrency is to generate a stored procedure that takes the value to insert, which generates the ID itself.

To do so, create a new table that contains the last post ID. Then, use an `UPDATE ... OUTPUT` statement to increment and return in one go. This is the only way to do an atomic update of the post ID so that no two users create the same ID.

Example Table PostIDTable

```
Current
=======
0
```

Example SELECT to update and retrieve the current post ID:

```
-- We need a temp table, because OUTPUT can not output into a single variable
-- This increments Current by one and outputs the value that was set in one go.
-- This prevents simultaneous calls to get the same ID
DECLARE #postID (ID INT)
UPDATE PostIDTable
OUPUT INSERTED.Current INTO #postID
SET
    Current = Current + 1

-- Get the value from the temp table and convert it into the desired format
DECLARE @pID INT = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM #postID)
DECLARE @id NVARCHAR(6) = 'PO' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @pID), 4)

-- Do the actual INSERT
INSERT INTO (PostDet, Votes,UserID) VALUES (@id, ..., ...)
```

Comment: sir i new to this field so how can i use this Code in and i earlier post my current code that i coded, please help me . .  thank you

Comment: 1) Create the table I mentioned. 2) Create a stored procedure that contains the code I wrote. 3) In C# use an SQL Command to call the stored procedure with the values you want to insert as parameter (CommandType = StoredProcedure). If you have troubles with that, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the PostID column to be an IDENTITY(1,1) column (in case of using MSSQL. server). So when you will insert new rows to your database the corresponding PostID values will be autogenerated by your database. The same holds for each other RDBMS you may use.

Having done the above change you code will change to the following:

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PostQuery = "INSERT INTO [Post] (PostDet,Votes,UserID) VALUES("TxtPost.Text + "','12','Us001')";
    dbClass.ConnectDataBaseToInsert(PostQuery);
    Response.Redirect("~/computing.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If PostId is autogenerated, only do this:

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PostQuery = "INSERT INTO [Post] (PostDet,Votes,UserID) VALUES('" + TxtPost.Text + "','12','Us001')";
    dbClass.ConnectDataBaseToInsert(PostQuery);
    Response.Redirect("~/computing.aspx");
}
```

Removing PostId from your query, it will generate the next Id

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use auto increment column ID for your table.
Please, see [w3school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) where is described construction for all main db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`select * from tablename order by id desc limit 1`

where id would be your primary key attribute name.